# Excel VBA Index Match Dynamic Range

Tags: vba, excel

*UPDATE:  All wording in Italics has been changed as I do not feel my question was answered.*

Unfortunately all of the other similarly named questions were much more detailed than I believe mine is.  As such all of my google searches have yielded zero fruits and I am back asking you excel WIZARDS.

Basically I want to index match a dynamic range.  The input data is variable based on which week of data are being queried but the good thing is the worksheet is always the same as *is the columns however the column length is variable*.  Typically I would use a LastRow function here but that isn't possible as it used reference cells for the formula.  This may come across as extremely simple to some of you.  See below:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('Consolidation Sheet'!R8C2:R6477C2,MATCH('Workbook 1'!RC[-1],'Consolidation Sheet'!R8C6:R6477C6,0))"

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Range("F4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F4:F" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault 'fill F column
```

For reference the "consolidation sheet" column is column B *or "2" in the reference code*.  What I am asking the Index Match to do is find the employees shift based on their employee number however the daily input of information is variable being that it is overtime data so I need the *column length* to be dynamic.  Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: Doesn't seem difficult at all. Use full column references; there is no detriment using them for either INDEX or MATCH. You might want to get rid of that ActiveCell and RC[-1] nonsense though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need to calculate with the Index/Match but the following shows the stages to make a dynamic Index/Match lookup. This assumes the data is sorted by employee

```
ColumnA - EmployeeName
ColumnB - EmployeeHours
ColumnC - StartRowOfEmployee =MATCH(A3,A:A,0)
ColumnD - EndRowOfEmployee =C3+COUNTIF(A:A,A3)-1
ColumnE - SumOfEmployeeHours =SUM(INDEX(B:B,C3,0):INDEX(B:B,D3,0))
```

This will be fast and non volatile. Essentially the dynamic element is built from chaining the INDEX's into SUM(Rng1:Rng2) where Rng1 and Rng2 are the dynamic start and end rows of the data.

[image]